# Add Magento functions to .php site

Tags: php, login

how can I add Magento functions to a php site? (For example: How can I add that the users have to sign in, if they want to view the page?)

Thanks!

Comment: So basically, you want to move parts of the Magento backend functionality to your own site? (for example logging in, creating an account and such?) If that is what you want, then you might wanna rethink that idea :p